# Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) when calling pygame.mixer.pre_init with a device name

Tags: audio, pygame, fatal-error

**Environment:**
I am on macOS Mojave and installed the latest version of PyGame. I am running the code to install the terminal.

You can get some of this info from the text that pops up in the console when you run a pygame program.

- **Operating system** MacOS Mojave.
- **Python version** 3.7.6

When I run the following code to change the output device with a device name as follows:

```
import pygame
import pygame._sdl2 as sdl2
pygame.init()
names = [str(sdl2.get_audio_device_name(i, 0), encoding="utf-8") for i in range(num)]
dev_name = names[0] # device number 
pygame.mixer.pre_init(devicename= dev_name)
```

It returns the following error with the mac error message to quit python as in the screenshot below. I tried this with the string literals such as:  "Sennheiser USB headset" or b'"Sennheiser USB headset" which are values returned from list "names" in above code. All of them return the same error as below.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you would require all this

```py
import pygame._sdl2 as sdl2
pygame.init()
names = [str(sdl2.get_audio_device_name(i, 0), encoding="utf-8") for i in range(num)]
dev_name = names[0] # device number 
pygame.mixer.pre_init(devicename= dev_name)
```

Try this

```py
import pygame
pygame.init() 
pygame.mixer.init()
```

Comment: I need to use a specific device as my audio output in my application. I don't want to select myself. I need python to select the output device.

Comment: ooohhh, ok, i didn't know that

Comment: Do you get the same error message as you run my code. It seems to be a bug! I wish there was a library to play two audio with fade in and out that works flawlessly on Mac.

Comment: I didn't run your code, only becoz i don't have same audio devices, so no error for me, and am on windows 10